# Is there any method to create an array containing consecutive zero or number type in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know one way to create consecutive zeros by using `for loop` and `push` method but I wonder whether there is method to create array containing consecutive zeros or number type.

looks like this
Array = [0,0,0......,0] or [Numbertype, Numbertype, Numbertype,....,Numbertype]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```js
const length = 10
const value = 0
const arr = Array(length).fill(value);
```